# Redis sequential unique id generation for distributed clients

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I need to generate sequential unique IDs for distributed clients.

1. I considered Redis in standalone mode, Jedis client, INCR command to
   increment a counter value against a key shared by all the
   clients. AOF `always` option enabled. This option is not good because of the
   standalone Redis server being SPOF and hence downtime for the clients.
2. The master and replicas with Sentinels setup is also not foolproof
   because there will always be a replication lag. It is not guaranteed
   that in case of master failure, there would be no data lag. I don't want to use the `WAIT` command to block in unbounded fashion. Consequently, the replicas would be slightly lagged and hence possible duplicate values might be visible to the clients.

Considering that, is Redis reliable for generating unique id sequence for concurrent clients?

Comment: How important is it for the IDs to be exactly sequential? E.g. if one client gets ID 11 one milisecond after another client gets ID 12, does that cause a problem?

Comment: @NickODell No, it's not a problem.

Comment: One route would be a [Snowflake-like](https://apoorvtyagi.tech/generating-unique-ids-in-a-large-scale-distributed-environment) system. That would have the advantage of not having a single point of failure (every worker has a distinct set of IDs it can generate.) The disadvantage is that it skips lots of numbers.